# template function instantiation and specialization

Tags: c++, function, templates

A bit confused on the template functions. I have the following:

```
template <class T> T max (T v1, T v2)

double max(double v1, double v2)        // non template
```

1)

```
int a = max(100, 200);  // assuming max<int> is instantiated based on input param
```

2)

```
int a = max<int>(100.1, 200.1);  // specialization triggers input type conversion
```

3)

```
double p = max<double>(100.1, 200.1);   // specialization
```

4)

```
double p = max(100.1, 200.1);          // non-template function used
```

(1)    is invocation without max considered valid? How does compiler handle this?
(3vs4) how does compiler track invoking max(double>() v/s max()?

Answer (score 0):

There are rules of function template overloading:

"If a function and a specialization are equally good matches, the function is preferred."

So, `max(double, double)` is preferred over `max<double>(double, double)`.

Compiler can distinguish ordinary function from template instantiation candidate and [gives precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163754.aspx#S3) to a non-template as it is "more real".

How a compiler distinguishes the functions? It uses [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), say [adding a letter 'H'](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.aix.doc/compiler_ref/opt_namemangling.html) for the template instantiated functions. The exact way of name mangling is compiler specific.

Answer (score 0):

All are perfectly valid, the compiler will figure out what you want most of the time if the inputs/output match.

Be aware that by declaring a new `max` function for `double`s you've told it you want them handled in a special way and it will search for your special implementation. This allows you to make special cases where the default template might not work.

Answer (score 0):

When choosing from overloads, the compiler first check non-template version. Since implicit casting is not encouraged, the compiler wont consider it as a perfect choice. Then the compiler check template version and find its true love(both of them don't need to change themselves and they are fit to each).

But consider this case

```
double max(double v1, double v2);

template <typename T>
T max(double v1, double v2);

int a = max(1,2);
```

If you enable the compiler to show the highest level warning(ex: W4 in VS), you would get a warning C4244(casting double to int) as the compiler choose non-template version. The compiler does not consider the return value when make the choice.